# Issue with T4 Templates for ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, t4

I'm trying to get T4 to work with ASP.NET, however when I create a textfile and rename it to .tt, I don't get the option to run it

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Visual Studio version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off - you can't "run" the file - you can run the **custom tool** on that file to generate the output.

I would recommend you use `Add New Item` from your project context menu, and then select `Text File` and give it a .tt extension right from the beginning. Then the T4 magic works without any hitch - whenever you save the file, or choose `Run Custom Tool` from the context menu on the file in the Solution Explorer, the template will be converted into its output.

If you have a file where that doesn't work now, do this: select the *.tt file in your Solution Explorer and have a look at the Properties window. In the "Custom Tool" text box, enter the value of **`TextTemplatingFileGenerator`**.

[image]

Now, the next time you save your file (Ctrl-S), you should get the output generated behind it.

**UPDATE:** the issues that the T4 templates don't work in an ASP.NET **website** project type seems to have been fixed in Visual Studio 2010. See Gareth Jones' blog post [What's New in T4 in Visual Studio 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/garethj/2010/04/15/whats-new-in-t4-in-visual-studio-2010/) for details.

Comment: That is the issue, inside an ASP.NET website, I am not getting that option, only in ClassLibrary or WinForm projects, does t4 work within an asp.net project?

Comment: Thanks.. will convert and try it

Answer (score 0):

Does it not run the transformation when you hit compile ? AFAIK there is no explicit "run transformation" option.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this, you can't add T4 templates to a Visual Studio 2008, ASP.NET Project.  You can however use T4 templates in a standard Class Library project in VS 2008.  So you can just add a Class Library Project to your ASP.NET solution, add your templates there, and then add that as a project Reference. Or upgrade to VS 2010, but that's not always an option.